# Is there a way to highlight all identical cells to that of the cell selected in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet that does not contain tables just separated cells and was wondering whether there was a way that when you select a cell, cells with the same value also become highlighted. I've tried a bit with conditional formatting but that only seems to work permanently, I only want the highlighting to occur when a cell. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Tomas